# Android Room auto-generate and initialization

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, auto-generate

I have a Room database that contains *Stuff* entities. These entities have an ID that will be auto-generated:

```
@Entity(tableName = "stuff")
data class Stuff(val text: String) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0
}
```

There are two things I don't like with my code:

1. I am initializing the id with 0, even though it should be initialized by Room.
2. The id data member is mutable.

I tried using *lateinit var* but the compiler wouldn't let me do it on a primitive type. Is there a way to overcome the two issues mentioned above in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

what do think about solving this using a secondary constructor?

```
@Entity(tableName = "stuff")
data class Stuff(
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  val id: Int,
  val text: String
) {
   constructor(text: String) : this(0,text)
}
```